# Return list of objects from another list using binary search

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of objects "Deliveries", each object holds few properties and another object of a class Person which stands for buyer of a deliverable.

The problem is that original list can contain multiple deliveries for the same buyer. And when I am trying to search for particular buyer see his deliveries (using binary search) i get as a return only 1 object (1 delivery) but i need all of them if there are more then one.

In order to solve this problem I have a method that returns a list of Deliveries for particular buyer with all of his deliverable's. This method is of type 
List Deliverable's  and has one parameter string for buyers name.

I can not figure out the implementation for this method, even that I think I understand how it should work. I have been struggling for the past hour or so, this is what I have so far....

```
public List<Deliverable> FindAllDeliverables(String buyersName)
{
    int lowindex = 0;
    int highindex = myDeliverables.Count - 1;
    List<Deliverable> additionalList = new List<Deliverable>();
    int m;  // for middle index
    while (lowindex <= highindex)
    {  // P
        m = (lowindex + highindex) / 2;

        if (myDeliverables[m].Buyer.Name == buyersName)
        {

            if (additionalList.Count == 0)
            {
                additionalList.Add(myDeliverables[m]);
            }
            else
            {

                foreach (Deliverable d in additionalList)
                {
                    if (d.ID == myDeliverables[m].ID)
                    {
                            /// do nothing >?
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        additionalList.Add(myDeliverables[m]);
                    }
                }


            }

        }
        else if (string.Compare(myDeliverables[m].Buyer.Name, buyersName) < 0)
        {
            lowindex = m + 1;
        }
        else if (string.Compare(myDeliverables[m].Buyer.Name, buyersName) > 0)
        {
            highindex = m - 1;
        }

    }
    return additionalList;

}
```

Comment: The Problem is in misunderstanding eligibility criteria for binary search. You can use only if case deliverables is ordered by Buyers name. And in this case algorithm will be following:  
1. Using binary search find first item which satisfy condition (belong to buyersName)(1). If found add to additionalList, if not - exit;  
2. Linear scan above (till items satisfy condition (1)) and add them to additionalList;  
3. Linear scan bellow (till items satisfy condition (1)) and add them to additionalList;

Comment: Hey @lerthe61 thanks for your reply. Yes i do sort a list by name before search . Is there a way to ignore the object that is already in the additional list during binary search. Because loop is ongoing without stop for that object.

Comment: Can you just use LINQ? `additionalList = myDeliverables.Where(x => x.Buyer.Name==buyersName).ToList()` unless you have a very big list or very many queries (in which case you can Group the original list by Buyer and use that grouping) you can replace lots of code with one line.